# NodeJS Forever's restarting function is not working when app gets an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

I develop parsing app with NodeJS and Puppeteer. It works well but sometimes web page is not loaded so it gives me an error. So I fix my code and I only need to restart the app when the error comes.

I found that forever can restart the app when it has an error. So I start my app with this command

```
forever start -o out.log -e err.log band.js
```

But even If app got some error it didn't start it again. Just it stops and do nothing.

**[ERROR Message]**

```
(node:11032) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
    at C:\Users\Downloads\Projects\Bander-Statistics\band.js:67:47
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:11032) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11032) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**[band.js]**

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
let article = fs.readFileSync("db.txt");
let lineArray = article.toString().split('\n')[0];

/* Initial Setting */
const initData = {
    chromePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
    userDataDir: 'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data',
    bandNum: 58075840,  // Parse Band Number
    startNum: lineArray,    // This variable will be read in db.txt first line
    untilNum: 90000 // Parse Until What Number
}

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); // Puppeteer 모듈 Load

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ // Puppeteer 모듈을 사용하지 않고 기존의 크롬 사용자 정보를 사용 (Auth 인증을 패스하기 위하여)
        executablePath: initData.chromePath,
        userDataDir: initData.userDataDir, // 설치시 개인 크롬 Directory로 수정하여야함
        headless: true
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage(); // Broswer Open
    await page.setViewport({ // Viewport 설정 가로의 경우 일반적으로 최대 1920, 새로의 경우 예상되는 최대 px를 지정해주면됨
        width: 800,
        height: 6000
    });
    page.on('dialog', async dialog => { // 삭제된 게시글의 경우 Band에서 Dialog를 띄우는데 이를 제거하기 위하여 필요
        console.log(dialog.message());
        await dialog.dismiss(); // Dialog 창 닫음
        await postNumber++; // 삭제된 게시글의 경우 Dialog 창이 닫힌후에 이전 URL로 돌아가므로 postNumber 1증가 시켜줌
        await page.goto(`https://band.us/band/${initData.bandNum}/post/${postNumber}`, {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
        });
    })
    let postNumber = initData.startNum; // 시작되는 PostNumber * 이 부분 부터 시작 *
    while (postNumber <= initData.untilNum) { // PostNumber 끝값 * 이 부분은 마지막 값 *
        await page.goto(`https://band.us/band/${initData.bandNum}/post/${postNumber}`, {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle0' // 페이지가 완전히 Load된후 작동
        });

        let [by, date] = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const textNode = document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0];
            const timeNode = document.getElementsByClassName('time')[0];
            return [
                textNode && textNode.innerText,
                timeNode && timeNode.innerText,
            ];
        });
        if (!by || !date) {
            // by or date is undefined
            console.log(`Not working for ID: ${postNumber}`);
            await page.reload()
            postNumber++;
            console.log('ERROR!')
            // await element.screenshot({ path: `error-${postNumber}.png` });
            await page.goto(`https://band.us/band/${initData.bandNum}/post/${postNumber}`, {
                waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
            });
        }

        let element = await page.$('.boardList'); // 게시글, 댓글 전체 Class
        await element.screenshot({ // ScreenShot Function
            path: `./image/${postNumber}-${by.replace("/","_")}-${date.replace(":","_")}.png` // 파일 저장 위치 & 파일이름 지정, replace 메소드의 경우 Windows 탐색기에서 :를 파일명으로 지원하지 않기때문
        });
        console.log(`${postNumber}-${by.replace("/","_")}-${date.replace(":","_")}.png`) // Console.log에서 파일 확인
        let lastTriedNum = postNumber;
        fs.writeFileSync("db.txt", '\ufeff' + lastTriedNum + '\n', {
            encoding: 'utf8'
        });
        await postNumber++; // 최종 성공시 postnumber 증가
    }
    await browser.close(); // 종료
})();
```

I already tried Supervisor, PM2, Forever but non of them provide the function I wanted.

I just need the ability to restart the whole app if an error occurs.

Comment: what was the command which you've tried with PM2?

Comment: @TejashwiKalpTaru I just use PM2 start command